# How to use `merge` instead of `plyr::join(x,y,type='full')`?

Tags: r

```
x <- data.frame(k1 = c(NA,NA,3,4,5), a2 = c(1,NA,NA,4,5), dat = 1:5)
y <- data.frame(k1 = c(NA,2,NA,4,5), k2 = c(NA,NA,3,4,5), data = 1:5)
plyr::join(x,y,type='full')
```

Output of above script is:

```
  k1 a2 dat k2 data
1 NA  1   1 NA    1
2 NA  1   1  3    3
3 NA NA   2 NA    1
4 NA NA   2  3    3
5  3 NA   3 NA   NA
6  4  4   4  4    4
7  5  5   5  5    5
8  2 NA  NA NA    2
```

As I have no `plyr` package, I decide to use `merge(x, y, all=TRUE,sort=FALSE)` instead of `plyr::join(x,y,type='full')`,output as below:

```
> merge(x, y, all=TRUE,sort=FALSE)
  k1 a2 dat k2 data
1 NA  1   1 NA    1
2 NA  1   1  3    3
3 NA NA   2 NA    1
4 NA NA   2  3    3
5  4  4   4  4    4
6  5  5   5  5    5
7  3 NA   3 NA   NA
8  2 NA  NA NA    2
```

You can find different row order of **row `6,7,8`** between 2 methods.

As row order is critical to my project,how to use `merge` get the same result as `plyr::join(x,y,type='full')`?

Comment: Please read the duplicate link, which is basically your exact question.  If you can't find what you're looking for there, then drop a comment and someone can reopen this question.

Comment: If you have `dplyr`, then use `full_join(x, y)`

Comment: @akrun,you are right. I just cannot imagine R has so many similar functions.

Comment: @kittygirl  `plyr` is kind of deprecated and gave way to `dplyr`.  But, there are still some functions in `plyr` that doesn't have a replacement in `dplyr`